# Send email with SendGrid API using Office365 email account A which is set to send on behalf of an email account B

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am facing an issue with SendGrid API.
I have added a single user related to an Office365 email account, let's say **a@tony.gr**. This account has been configured to send on behalf of an other email account, let's say **b@tony.gr**.

I tried to implement a simple console application in C#, which sends an email message to a recipient from **b@tony.gr**.

```
var from = new EmailAddress("b@tony.gr", "B Account");
var subject = "Test";
var to = new EmailAddress("foo@foo.com", "Recipient");
var plainTextContent = "Hello world !!";
var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, null);
var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

When I execute the above code even if I do not get any error the mail is not sent.
However, when I set as "from" account the email account **a@tony.gr** the email is sent. I imagine that I have to include the added single user **a@tony.gr** in my code, but I don't know how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you have "added a single user" I assume you mean you have [verified that email address as a single sender](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification).

SendGrid has no concept of Office365's configuration and the ability for **a@tony.gr** to be able to send a message on behalf of **b@tony.gr**. Your Office365 settings have no effect on how SendGrid works.

If you want to send emails from **b@tony.gr** then you will need to also [verify that email address with SendGrid](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification).

Comment: Hello @philnash. Many thanks for your reply.
Yes, I have verified "a@tony.gr" address as a single sender.

Comment: However, it's important for us to be able to send emails using an account on behalf of other accounts. 
Is there a solution that Twilio can provide us?

Comment: You can set up [domain authentication](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication) for the entire domain. That will allow you to send emails from any address on the domain from SendGrid.